# using switch statement inside a button

Tags: swift

Please help and I'm sorry if this is covered somewhere else although i have looked elsewhere and whilst there are answers to my topic i cannot find one for my problem. so if anyone could help that would be great.

basically i am trying to do a switch statement inside a button so that when i click the button the statement activates in my label, but for some reason i cannot get it to work
here is my code below

[image]

when i hit run it always shows the "This is an even number between 0 and 10" regardless of even number, odd number or large number

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images. Post code as text.

Comment: you pas only even number that's why always return even.... change the number varible to 1 its return odd

Comment: Thanks very much Should I post again or leave it

Comment: number is always 6 ! when you change it ?

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Divyesh but I am wanting to insert a number into my text box and the message appear in the label. I am new to all this so I'm sure there is a simple way that I'm just not seeing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before the `switch` line you have to add three lines to assign the value of the input text field to the variable `number`.

```
guard let inputText = numberInput.text, let input = Int(inputText) else {
                      numberOutput.text = "Please enter a number!" 
                      return }
number = input
```

Comment: Tried this but xcode told me "guard body may not fall through, consider using a return or throw to exit the scope" . Thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot the `return` statement.

Comment: I know this sound silly to you but what am I returning

Comment: Nothing. You are exiting the function.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in playground, always prints expected output.

```
var number = 6

switch  number {
case 0,2,4,6,8,10:
    print("even")
case 1,3,5,7,9:
    print("odd")
default:
    print("higher")
}
```

where are you changing the number variable? Are you doing it on one of the callback methods for textfield delegate?

Comment: I was changing the number variable in my text box when i run the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

you are not changing the value of your var `number`. Looks like it is always 6 based from your code

Comment: What code would i need to use in order to input a number in my textField and it prints the relevant statement in my label. Thanks

Comment: You can add a `number = numberInput.text` right before the switch statement

Comment: This did not work. Told me I basically couldn't mix Int with Str

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
import UIKit

class EmptyViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonHit(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if let text = textField.text, let number = Int(text)
        {
            switch number {
            case 0,2,4,6,8,10:
                label.text = "Even"
            case 1,3,5,7,9:
                label.text = "Odd"
            default:
                label.text = "Higher"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            label.text = "Please enter a valid number"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PGDev tried this and works great. Appreciate it